# How to check if a batch file has ANY parameters?

Tags: cmd.exe

I'm using a batch file that has these statements at the start, to check if all four parameters it is designed for are there, and to quit if any of them are missing. The code is:

```
IF "%~1"=="" EXIT /B
IF "%~2"=="" EXIT /B
IF "%~3"=="" EXIT /B
IF "%~4"=="" EXIT /B
```

The trouble is, this code seems mightily inefficient. Is there a simple way of checking for any parameters and quitting if there aren't?

Comment: Sorry, its unclear what you are asking. Do you want to confirm that there are at least four parameters? Or that there are exactly four parameters? Or something else?

Comment: I want the batch file to determine if there is anything after the batch file name when it is called, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comment you gave, your code is indeed inefficient. You can remove last three lines and just keep:

```
IF "%~1"=="" EXIT /B
```

This will check for the first parameter only. It will exit if batch is called without params OR will continue if the batch has one ore more params